# Haskell http client browser simulation

Tags: haskell

I'm thinking of using low level http client library to simulate a real browser.

Below is the exmaple code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Client

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let settings = managerSetProxy
            (proxyEnvironment Nothing)
            defaultManagerSettings
    man <- newManager settings
    let req = "http://httpbin.org"
            -- Note that the following settings will be completely ignored.
            { proxy = Just $ Proxy "localhost" 1234
            }
    httpLbs req man >>= print
```

Which part could I customize? the `req` or manager settings? Could anyone show me an example how to simulate below Chrome request headers?

```
:authority: example.com
:method: GET
:path: /ebooks/1/added/desc.html
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4
cache-control: max-age=0
referer: https://torlock.unblocked.gdn/ebooks/1/added/desc.html
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Btw: Is it enough for a website to think it's a brower accessing it just by modifying the request header?

Comment: `"http://httpbin.org" {` looks like a type error.

Comment: @melpomene It's a made-up site. Not important

Comment: Ah, it's not a type error because of OverloadedStrings. Are you simply looking for http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.13.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:requestHeaders?